# How to get Vite.js to work in Wordpress/Wordplate

Tags: wordpress, vite

I have Wordplate/Wordpress Website that I'm currently working on.
And Wordplate/Wordpress comes with Vite.

Now my problem is, I'm trying to get Vite to work in Wordpress, like HMR.

What I really want is, everytime I update my `index.scss`, the site gets those updates.

Now, I've overwritten the default `vite.config.js` to this

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

require("dotenv").config();

export default defineConfig(() => ({
  publicDir: "resources/static",
  build: {
    assetsDir: "",
    emptyOutDir: true,
    manifest: true,
    outDir: `public/themes/${process.env.WP_DEFAULT_THEME}/assets`,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: `public/themes/${process.env.WP_DEFAULT_THEME}/resources/js/index.js`,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      name: "php",
      handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
        if (file.endsWith(".php")) {
          server.ws.send({ type: "full-reload", path: "*" });
        }
      },
    },
  ],
}));
```

My `index.js`

```js
import "../css/index.css";
```

The `index.css` is the ouput of my `index.scss` where I write my css code and then outpout it to `index.css`. The `index.css` is then the file been used by my child theme to apply styles.

This is the `functions.php` of my child team that loads my js and my css

```php
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');

// Register scripts and styles.
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    $manifestPath = get_theme_file_path('assets/manifest.json');

    if (
        wp_get_environment_type() === 'local'
        && is_array(wp_remote_get('http://localhost:5173/')) // is Vite.js running
    ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('vite', 'http://localhost:5173/@vite/client', [], null);
        wp_enqueue_script('vite', 'http://localhost:5173/resources/js/index.js', [], null);
    } elseif (file_exists($manifestPath)) {
        $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents($manifestPath), true);
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'vite',
            get_theme_file_uri('assets/' . $manifest['resources/js/index.js']['file']),
            [],
            null
        );
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'vite',
            get_theme_file_uri('assets/' . $manifest['resources/css/index.css']['file']),
            [],
            null
        );
    }
});

// Load scripts as modules.
add_filter('script_loader_tag', function (string $tag, string $handle, string $src) {
    if (in_array($handle, ['vite', 'vite'])) {
        return '<script type="module" src="' . esc_url($src) . '" defer></script>';
    }

    return $tag;
}, 10, 3);
```

Actualy, everytime I make some changes in my `index.scss` and then I manually refresh the browser, I can see the changes.

But I don't want to do it manually, I want it to be automaic.

Please if someone have done this, I need your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I just used the default `vit.config.js`

In my js, `wordplate/resources/js/index.js` I imported the css from my child-theme

```js
import '../../public/themes/Divi-child/style.css';
```

Then I made my `index.scss` to compile into my `style.css` child theme.

And that's it.

so my `vite.config.js` looks like this

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

require("dotenv").config();

export default defineConfig(() => ({
  publicDir: "resources",
  build: {
    assetsDir: "",
    emptyOutDir: true,
    manifest: true,
    outDir: `public/themes/${process.env.WP_DEFAULT_THEME}/assets`,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: `resources/js/index.js`,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      name: "php",
      handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {
        if (file.endsWith(".php")) {
          server.ws.send({ type: "full-reload", path: "*" });
        }
      },
    },
  ],
}));
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the repository for the whole thing? I'd love to learn from ground up.